# theano T.switch(): if tensor is empty strange behaviour

Tags: python, if-statement, theano

i want to check if vector `A is empty: return [0] else: return A`

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

A = T.ivector()

out = T.switch( T.eq(A.size, 0), [0], A )

f = theano.function([A], out)

print f([1])
print f([])
```

this prints:

```
[ 1 ]
[]
```

the conditional statement by itself works, it only returns 1 if A is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`theano.tensor.switch` operates differently to `theano.ifelse.ifelse`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conditions.html).

`theano.tensor.switch` operates element-wise. The three arguments need to have the same shape, or be broadcastable to the same shape. `T.eq(A.size, 0)` will always be a scalar and the true value, `[0]` is a vector with a single element so both will be broadcast to the shape of `A`. The case of `A == []` is undoubtedly odd and I don't know if it is by design; Theano appears to be "broadcasting" the scalar and single entry vector to the empty vector.

The solution is to switch to `theano.ifelse.ifelse`:

```
A = tt.ivector()
out = theano.ifelse.ifelse(
    tt.eq(A.size, 0), tt.unbroadcast(tt.zeros((1,), dtype=A.dtype), 0), A)
f = theano.function([A], out)
print f([])
print f([1])
print f([1, 2])
```

As desired, this prints

```
[0]
[1]
[1 2]
```

Note that the two possible `ifelse` output values (the value if the comparison is true and the value if the comparison is false) must have identical types, hence the convoluted method for constructing a zeros vector with a single entry.

Comment: thanks for the concise answer! if i may, is it correct in assuming that that convoluted unbroadcasting is most heavy on the compile time of the code if the condition for an empty vector is rarely met?

Comment: Whether the empty vector condition is rarely met or not will have no effect on the compile time since that happens before any data is seen. The unbroadcasting is a trivial operation that should have little impact on either compile or run time.